# Редактировать прогресс бар. Добавление дополнительных элементов в виде div или любой другой

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, progress-bar

У меня есть прогресс бар в самом обычном виде:

```
<progress id="file" max="100" value="70"> 70% </progress>
```

Можно ли создать прогресс бар в таком формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот блок должен следовать за прогрессом и выводить число процентов

Comment: тут по любому костылить надо

Comment: У вас нет примеров?

Comment: а как  эта полоска работает - что показывает или какое у неё поведение ?

Comment: Через php вместо value вставляются данные в виде переменной <?=$progress?>. Я вас отмечу и буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Там есть range подёргай за него ... если кастомные теги не хочешь можешь изменить на div

Если надо объяснения то спроси я отвечу

```js
let range = document.querySelector("#range");
let line = document.querySelector("line");
let info = document.querySelector("info");

range.oninput = function() {
  line.style.width = this.value * 6 + "px";
  info.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
};
```

```css
wrap,
line,
info {
  display: block;
}

wrap {
  width: 600px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  position: relative;
}

line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

info {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<wrap>
  <line>
    <info>10%</info>
  </line>
</wrap>

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10" id="range">
```

```js
let line = document.querySelector("line");
let info = document.querySelector("info");

range.oninput = function() {
  line.style.width = this.value + "px";
  info.innerHTML = parseInt(this.value / 3) + "%";
};
```

```css
wrapper,
line,
info {
  display: block;
}

wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0576fb;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

info {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <line>
    <info>70%</info>
  </line>
</wrapper>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="range" id="range" min="40" max="300" value="210">
```

Comment: "Кастомные" теги, это что-то новенькое? Какие есть проблемы с этим?

Comment: @OliverPatterson прямо щас проверьте везде - если хоть где то не работает - напишите мне об этом - я как 8 лет это делаю и пока не было проблем кроме validator.w3.org

Comment: Мне просто интересно ибо слышал, что новые HTML5 теги допустим не работают в IE каком-то там. С этими тегами такого не будет?

Comment: @OliverPatterson я в ie давненько не был так как линуксоид - а ваще на всех даже на самых дряхлых андроидах работают ... на винде тоже давно не был ... хотя ща включу и проверю

Comment: @OliverPatterson не уверен что люди работающие на винде xp с IE11 целевая аудитория какого-либо сайта, а если и так - они давно привыкли что у низ 90% сайтов не работает)), есть множество сайтов написанных на angular, react там ширко используются кастомные теги.

Comment: Почему когда я ставлю значения с 0 до 100 то прогресс не доходит до половины?? https://ibb.co/PD8VbmD

Comment: @AlexMiller это простая математика - там 300 должно быть

Comment: @AlexMiller  там через innerHTML выводится parseInt (this.vlaue/ 3 ) а value = 300

Comment: Второй код мне больше подошёл. Спасибо! Возник один вопрос, а чем можно заменить "oninput" что бы при загрузке данных элементы с процентами уже были готовы?

Comment: @AlexMiller я не знаю - задайте вопрос в котором подробно опишите что вы хотите и почему вариант с моего ответа вам кажется не корректным

Comment: Я решил тем, что вставил php код умножив на 6 вместо width: <?=$code?>. Работает, очень благодарен, спасибо!